# How to retrieve all rows from a database table and loop through each row to match password PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i need to pull all the rows from the database table and loop through each of them to find a row that matches both the Msisdn and Password? please help guys...

```
        $state = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $state->execute();
        $userRow = $state->fetchAll();
        foreach($userRow as $dataObj) {
            if($userData['msisdn'] === $dataObj['Msisdn']) {
                if($userData['userpass'] === $dataObj['Password']) {
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $dataObj['id'];
                    if($_SESSION['user_id'] == true) {
                        echo "You're logged in...";
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<font color='red'>" . "{$error} <b>Incorrect PIN</b>. Please enter again, you have <b>2 attempts</b> remaining." . "</font><br><br>";
                    echo "<font color='slateGrey'>contact us on <a>086 000 3344</a> to register or request a </font><a target='_blank' href='support@example.co.za'>callback.</a>";
                    return false;
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                echo "<font color='red'>" . "{$error} User not found... Please contact your service provider..." . "</font><br><br>";
                echo "<font color='slateGrey'>either call on <a>086 000 3344</a> or request</font> <a href='support@example.co.za'>callback.</a>";
                return false;
                exit();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What is the result of your current code and what have you tried to get the behavior you desire?

Comment: Only the first user on the table can successfully log in, but when i try to login using other registered users on the table I get the error "User not found... Please contact your service provider..."

Comment: I hope you're not storing raw passwords in your DB

Comment: no i've created a custom hashing function...

Comment: But now the issue is 1, everything works perfectly fine my only problem is that the return data only returns 1 row from all the tables i.e other users are sort of 'dont exist'...

Comment: oh yes i found a much better way of achieving my initial goal... thanks guys...

Comment: What was that If I may ask?

Answer (score 6):

The whole point of using a database is that you don't have to do this! That's why an RDBMS provides a WHERE clause to the SELECT statement. If you have indexed your table properly, the RDBMS only needs to look up a few rows to find the matching entry (if available). So you don't have to write all this code. Yourself.

```
$password = hashing_fuciont($dataObj['Password']);  /* you are hashing the password aren't you? */

$stmt = $state->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where username=? password=?")
$stmt->execute( array("username"=>$username, "password"=>$password));
$userRow = $state->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thing is i joined 2 tables of which table-1 contains the 'username' and table-2 contains 'password' e.g 'SELECT table-1.id, table-1.username, table-2.Password FROM table-1, table-2 WHERE table-1.id = table-2.Id'

Comment: That's not a good structure. Every standard design of an authentication system I have seen (and I have seen very many) has the username and password in the same table.